# how to add checkbox element inside a radiobutton list

Tags: asp.net

my code looks something like this-:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList>
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem> //ToDo
  <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want to show `<asp:CheckBox>` element after the second list item is selected. 
So, the checkbox needs to appear between second and third list item. Is there anyway to do this? 
Right now I'm showing the checkbox after the radiobuttonlist element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with a `RadioButtonList`. You will have to use single RadioButtons with `GroupName` to create your own.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="MyGroup" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="MyGroup" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="MyGroup" />
```

UPDATE

It is sort of possible in a hacky way. And if it is useful depends on what you want to do with that checkbox.
Make the `Text` of a ListItem a html checkbox.

```
RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Text = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkBoxInsideList\" class=\"RadioButtonListWithCheckbox\">";
```

Then move it over the radio button

```
<style>
    .RadioButtonListWithCheckbox {
        margin-left: -16px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I see. I guess I need to redesign the whole thing

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible hack.

Comment: thanks, @VDWWD. I already made the change as you suggested the first time. I find it much more flexible in my case. I'll keep the hack in mind for the next time.